# How to make gradient ellipse title box with border?

Tags: titles, boxes, tcolorbox, gradient

I am using the `tcolorbox` package, and I want to use a gradient ellipse title box with border on the titlepage. It is possible somehow or I have to use another package to manage this?

Comment: Maybe try to do that with TikZ/PGF? (read their manual)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the last one to discourage you using `tcolorbox`, but for this I would use TikZ directly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{3cm}

\begin{center}
\tikz[scale=4.5,transform shape]
  \node[ellipse,line width=1pt,
    align=center,
    font=\bfseries,
    draw=blue!50!red,
    top color=blue!30,
    bottom color=red!30]
  {This is\\ my Title};
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

To split the shadings, you could use a 'middle color' or for sharp splitting, a new vertical shading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{3cm}

\begin{center}
\tikz[scale=4.5,transform shape]
  \node[ellipse,line width=1pt,
    align=center,
    font=\bfseries,
    draw=blue!50!red,
    top color=blue!30,
    bottom color=red!30,
    middle color=yellow
    ]
  {This is\\ my Title};
\end{center}


\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshading}{100bp}{
  color(0bp)=(blue!50!black);
  color(50bp)=(blue!20);
  color(50bp)=(red!30);
  color(100bp)=(red!10!yellow)
}

\begin{center}
\tikz[scale=4.5,transform shape]
  \node[ellipse,line width=1pt,
    align=center,
    font=\bfseries,
    draw=blue!50!red,
    shading=myshading
    ]
  {This is\\ my Title};
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, and it is possible to use circle split node with different gradient at the upper and lower half?

Comment: @user3058699 See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, but i do not understand clearly. draw and shading is bottom and top? why are they treated differently?

Comment: @user3058699 This is *normal* TikZ code. `draw` is for the outline of a shape and `fill` or `shading` for the interior.